# close Kafka via TERMINAL

Tags: windows, cmd, apache-kafka

Hi I'm newby Kafka and I succedded in starting a Kafka server in windows (via Terminal) follwing this documentation:
https://dzone.com/articles/running-apache-kafka-on-windows-os
https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

My question is easy, how should I close KAfka correctly via cmd terminal in windows?

The problem is that when I close the different terminals (in order to shut down my computer) I'm not able to start it again beceause kafka runs out of memory and fataly crashes

```
 ERROR Error while loading log dir C:\Users\u1\Desktop\kafka-logs (kafka.log.LogManager)
java.io.IOException: Map failed
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:944)
        at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.<init>(AbstractIndex.scala:126)
.
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Map failed
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:941)
```

Is there any way to close my consumer, producer, topic, kafka and producer correctly using terminal comands?

[image]
I found a lot of documentation about closing it via code but this is not my question.
[Closing a Kafka connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26776659/closing-a-kafka-connection)

-------- UPDATE-------
I don´t know how to declare the winner of the solution because both (Robin Moffatt, Mukesh Prajapati) are right. Because when I press CTRL + C, my terminal asks me about closing the program that is executing. Also when I restart it, works perfectly. 
In the other hand the solution provided by Mukesh Prajapati also works like charm, as you can see in the following screen it closes the instance of the zookeper. (thanks both for your help)
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To shutdown `Zookeeper`, use following command:

```
bin\windows\zookeeper-server-stop.bat config\zookeeper.properties
```

To shutdown `Kafka Server`, use following command:

```
bin\windows\kafka-server-stop.bat config\server.properties
```

Comment: got this: `process - Alias not found.`

Answer (score 2):

You need to shut Kafka down gracefully. 
On Linux that would be with Ctrl-C in the terminal which sends a `SIGINT` to Kafka at which point it will shut down what it's doing and close its open files etc. I'm assuming the same will be true on Windows.

Comment: If I use Control+C seems zookeeper server still runs and conflicts on next start up. (ps -ef shows org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain /usr/local/etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties)  I used this command to startup zookeeper-server-start /usr/local/etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties & kafka-server-start /usr/local/etc/kafka/server.properties

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed `Kafka` using `Homebrew` then follow below commands to `start/stop` `Kafka` and `ZooKeeper`.

To start:

```
brew services start zookeeper
brew services start kafka
```

To list all services:

```
brew services list
```

To stop:

```
brew services stop zookeeper
brew services stop kafka
```

This is late post but may useful for others. :)